# Seekbar not moving with exoplayer android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, exoplayer

I'm building a music app, using exoplayer and on the music details fragment.
The seekbar doesnt move.

Here is the current behaviour, (The seekbar not moving unless I seek manually from touch)

[image]

**SongViewModel**

```
private val playBackState = musicServiceConnection.playbackState

private val _currentSongDuration = MutableLiveData<Long>()
val currentSongDuration: LiveData<Long> = _currentSongDuration

private val _currentPlayerPosition = MutableLiveData<Long>()
val currentPlayerPosition: LiveData<Long> = _currentPlayerPosition

init {
    updateCurrentPlayerPosition()
}

fun updateCurrentPlayerPosition(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        while (true){
            val position = playBackState.value?.currentPlaybackPosition
            if (currentPlayerPosition.value != position){
                _currentPlayerPosition.postValue(position!!)
                _currentSongDuration.postValue(MusicService.curSongDuration)
            }
            delay(UPDATE_PLAYER_POSITION_INTERVAL)
        }
    }
}
```

**SongDetailsFragment**

```
............
private val songViewModel: SongViewModel by viewModels()
.............

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 binding.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            if (fromUser) {
                updatePlayingTime(progress.toLong())
            }
        }
        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            shouldUpdateSeekBar = false
        }
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            binding.seekBar.let {
                mainViewModel.seekTo(it.progress.toLong())
                shouldUpdateSeekBar = true
            }
        }
    })

    private fun updatePlayingTime(ms: Long){
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
    binding.txtCurrentTime.text = dateFormat.format(ms)
   }

   //observe data here
   songViewModel.currentPlayerPosition.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){

        if (shouldUpdateSeekBar){
            binding.seekBar.progress = it.toInt()
            updatePlayingTime(it)
        }

    }

    songViewModel.currentSongDuration.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        binding.seekBar.max = it.toInt()
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss", 
     Locale.getDefault())
        binding.txtSongDuration.text = dateFormat.format(it)
    }

}
```

**fragmentsongdetails.xml**

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.35"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ic_like"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_current_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/app_name_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/seek_bar"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/seek_bar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seek_bar"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_song_duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/app_name_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_current_time"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/seek_bar"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.996"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_current_time"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txt_current_time"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

What could be the cause?
Let me know if I need to add more code - MusicServiceConnection Class or MusicService

Answer (score 1):

First use PlayerControlView and design your control according to your need please use
default exoplayer seekbar/DefaultTimeBar for your music player

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
   android:id="@id/exo_progress"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:tag="tint_accent_color" />
```

bind your SimpleExoPlayer object like this

```
public class AudioPlayerServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public SimpleExoPlayer getPlayer() {
        return player;
    } 
}
```

In your Activity or Fragment bind your SimpleExoPlayer object

```
private final ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
   @Override
   public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
   binder = (AudioPlayerService.AudioPlayerServiceBinder) service;
   serviceBound = true;
   player = binder.getPlayer();


   preview.setPlayer(player); //preview is the object of your custom control object

}
@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
   serviceBound = false;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your currentSongDuration LiveData to Seekbar `max` and currentPlayerPosition in Seekbar `progress` in xml. Also, you only need to set _currentSongDuration once and not on every player position update.

Comment: I am already doing that in my fragment. Please check updated question. I have added the code "//observe data here" in SongDetailsFragment. The seekbar not moving